# Rest api request throttling

Tags: rest-api

Couldn't find any information, so here I go.

### Does WordPress have a native request throttling behavior or not?

For instance Laravel gives you

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/rate-limiting

### If not

I know how to implement it myself but I'm a little short on time, so I want to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel here, so if you know any gist, repo, plugins to get me started please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this sound like the same thing? I wasn't sure from the Laravel docs, but there are a few security plugins that have rate limiting on a per-IP basis. https://getshieldsecurity.com/blog/shield-rate-limiting-protection-wordpress/

Or are you wanting to rate limit requests to the site as a whole, perhaps to protect server resources?

Comment: You might also find this useful: https://github.com/cedaro/wprestcop

Comment: @Nabha Thank you so much! I actually saw https://getshieldsecurity.com/blog/shield-rate-limiting-protection-wordpress/ before I post this but it has a lot more functionality sounds a little too much for this simple purpose, your second suggestion sounds a great starting point though it requires a persistent cache which is not available on most hostings.

Comment: I just found something for the cache with files which sounds amazing: https://github.com/nawawi/docket-cache/

Comment: You might as well post these as an answer, you sure deserve an upvote!

Comment: Will do, Steve, hope implementing your solution goes smoothly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't sure from the Laravel docs exactly how it works there, but there are a couple of security plugins (at least) that have rate limiting on a per-IP basis:

- [ShieldPRO](https://getshieldsecurity.com/blog/shield-rate-limiting-protection-wordpress/)
- [WordFence](https://www.wordfence.com/help/firewall/rate-limiting/)

This may be more useful, however, as it is focused only on rate limiting and isn't a product, and would be more flexible for you:

- [WP REST Cop](https://github.com/cedaro/wprestcop)

That one requires a persistent object cache — if you can't use Memcache or [Redis](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redis-cache/), there's this (which you found):

- [Docket Cache](https://github.com/nawawi/docket-cache/)

Answer (score 0):

I went with [WP Rest Cop](https://github.com/cedaro/wprestcop) as Nabha suggested and [Docket Cache](https://github.com/nawawi/docket-cache/)

Just installed them and they worked without issues, well not exactly! there was one issue which made me struggle to find out where it was coming from, it kept saying `rate_limit_exceeded` and never got reset!

So I did find the issue and did a [pull request](https://github.com/cedaro/wprestcop/pull/3) Here's my fork of it for now: https://github.com/Stevemoretz/wprestcop/tree/patch-1

Also I made its limits same as default of Laravel 60 times in 60 seconds with this hook:

```php
add_action( 'wprestcop_plugin_loaded', function( $wprestcop ) {
    $wprestcop
        ->set_limit( 60 )
        ->set_interval( MINUTE_IN_SECONDS );
} );
```